# Open link on scatter plot in Bokeh Python but do not immediately follow link

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am using the Bokeh module with Python and the following example:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, OpenURL, TapTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("openurl.html")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           tools="tap", title="Click the Dots")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    color=["navy", "orange", "olive", "firebrick", "gold"]
    ))

p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=20, source=source)

url = "http://www.colors.commutercreative.com/@color/"
taptool = p.select(type=TapTool)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)

show(p)
```

This all works, when I click one of the circles a new tab opens in my browser and the focus switches to that tab.

**Question**

However, I am interested in staying on the plotting page and simply letting the new tab open without switching focus to that tab.

Does anyone know how to do this? I imagine it is some keyword argument to "OpenURL(...)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12` there is no configuration option for that. You could definitely make a custom extension to do that, or alternatively if you'd like to see it in the core library it would make an excellent small PR for a new contributor to tackle (and I'd be happy to help get you started). In any event I'd encourage you to take this new feature request to the project mailing list or the project GitHub tracker.